# Cygwin MySQL installation asks for a root password. How can I get it?

Tags: mysql, installation, passwords, cygwin, root

I saw that in order to connect MYSQL database on cygwin, this statement must be e on itxecuted:

> mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1
> However, as far as I know, there's no root user on cygwin.
> How can I get that requested password?

I tried with an empty password and "root" word a password but no luck, so far.

please help out on it.
Thanks

I tried this:

> mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1

I expected a no error message